# Is it safe to put the entire user in a session vs just the user ID for node/express?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am using node/express and was wondering if it is safe to put the entire user object in the session rather than just the `Id`. If I do just the `Id` then this means I must make another DB call when I go to get the `currentUser`.

I have seen people do it, but if it is more safe to just put the Id then I will go about doing that. I should state that I would take the password off the user before attaching it to the session or any other sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing especially unsafe about it, but generally not considered a good practice. When you update your user data, you have to update your session and database, so now you have to keep those in sync, which creates challenges.

Also keep in mind your session store.  The more data in your session, the larger the storage requirements for your session store, maybe not a problem, but something to consider.